# How to generate a regular expression at runtime to match a numeric range

Tags: java, regex

I need to generate, at run time, a regular expression that will match a range of numeric values.

For example: At run time I may discover that I need a regular expression matching all the files in the "range" `a-261-b.something` to `a-543-b.something`.

I need to generate a regular expression that will match all of this files. Any ideas?

I need it in Java, so if anyone know any Java-specific way to so this, it's also acceptable.

Comment: Do you really need an regex? You can construct a java-regex for any number range but this is not the best way to do it.

Comment: Parsing out the numbers and doing a "manual" check for the range. See my answer.

Comment: I added some code for you in my answer.

Comment: Are actually looking for existing files?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whether or not regular expressions are well suited for this task is debatable. Most people would probably argue that it's not.

As I understand it however, you have no choice as the API you're using takes a regular expression as argument, so here goes...

### Code

```
public class NumericRangeRegexGenerator {

    private static String baseRange(String num, boolean up, boolean leading1) {

        char c = num.charAt(0);
        char low  = up ? c : leading1 ? '1' : '0';
        char high = up ? '9' : c;

        if (num.length() == 1)
            return charClass(low, high);

        String re = c + "(" + baseRange(num.substring(1), up, false) + ")";

        if (up) low++; else high--;

        if (low <= high)
            re += "|" + charClass(low, high) + nDigits(num.length() - 1);

        return re;
    }

    private static String charClass(char b, char e) {
        return String.format(b==e ? "%c" : e-b>1 ? "[%c-%c]" : "[%c%c]", b, e);
    }

    private static String nDigits(int n) {
        return nDigits(n, n);
    }

    private static String nDigits(int n, int m) {
        return "[0-9]" + String.format(n==m ? n==1 ? "":"{%d}":"{%d,%d}", n, m);
    }

    private static String eqLengths(String from, String to) {

        char fc = from.charAt(0), tc = to.charAt(0);

        if (from.length() == 1 && to.length() == 1)
            return charClass(fc, tc);

        if (fc == tc)
            return fc + "("+rangeRegex(from.substring(1), to.substring(1))+")";

        String re = fc + "(" + baseRange(from.substring(1), true, false) + ")|"
                  + tc + "(" + baseRange(to.substring(1),  false, false) + ")";

        if (++fc <= --tc)
            re += "|" + charClass(fc, tc) + nDigits(from.length() - 1);

        return re;
    }    

    private static String nonEqLengths(String from, String to) {
        String re = baseRange(from,true,false) + "|" + baseRange(to,false,true);
        if (to.length() - from.length() > 1)
            re += "|[1-9]" + nDigits(from.length(), to.length() - 2);
        return re;
    }

    public static String rangeRegex(int n, int m) {
        return rangeRegex("" + n, "" + m);
    }

    public static String rangeRegex(String n, String m) {
        return n.length() == m.length() ? eqLengths(n, m) : nonEqLengths(n, m);
    }

}
```

#### Usage

```
// Generate expression for range 123 - 321
String regexp = NumericRangeRegexGenerator.rangeRegex(123, 321);
```

### Explanation

A brief explanation of the code follows.

#### Ranges on the shape `0000`-`abcd` and `abcd`-`9999`

First we note that matching ranges such as `0000`-`abcd` is fairly easy.

An expression covering for instance `000`-`527` can be expressed as

- `[0-4]` followed by two arbitrary digits, or
- `5` followed by `00`-`27` (which is resolved recursively!)

Ranges on the shape `1000`-`abcd` and `abcd`-`9999` are just as easy.

#### Lower limit, upper limit of different lengths.

If the "from"-number is shorter than the "to"-number it is fairly straight forward.

Assume for instance that the `from`-number has 3 digits and the `to`-number has 7 digits. The expression can then be composed as follows:

- `from`-`999` (as described above),
- Any `4`, `5` or `6` digit number: `[1-9][0-9]{3-5}`, or
- `1000000`-`to` (as described above)

#### Lower limit / upper limit of equal lengths.

This is the trickiest situation (still not *that* tricky though!)

The solution is, again, best described by an example. Consider the range `273` - `548`. The expression can be composed by the following parts:

- `2` followed by `73`-`99` (latter part described above),
- `[34]` followed by any two digits, or
- `5` followed by `00`-`48` (latter part described above)

Comment: +1 That was so cool that I had to delete my own (poor) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I understand this correctly. You have a file named a-NUMBER-b.txt. You need to check that the number is the correct number. Here's how that's done:

To check the number, assuming it is in the right format:

```
String name = getName();
int myInt = Integer.parseInt(name.split(a + "-")[1].split("-" + b + ".txt")[0]);
```

To check the format:

```
name.startsWith(a + "-") && name.endWith("-" + b + ".txt")
```

Let me know if I answered correctly,
Ryan

Comment: Please note that a != b (or !a.equals(b) if you want to be picky)

Comment: this would be excellent, but i use a file event listener, that listens to files that are created in a dir. this is currently implemented with regex that validates if file x is one of the files that i need to get. so this resolution would force a change in the current implementation..

Comment: `split` is not a static method. `String.split` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @dan In the event listener, you should be able to feed in your own instance of the listener to use by providing a class that implements the given listener.

Comment: @aioob oops... I meant name.split. Thanks!

Comment: well if this is what need to be done, i'll do it. i thought that a regex can be built, as complex as it can be, to solve this..

Comment: @dan, it can. But it won't be a simple algorithm.

Comment: @dan, see my answer for such algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work, though not sure on the cost of the split.

```
File[] files = new File("foo").listFiles();
for( int i = 0; i < files.length; i++ )
{
    String fn = files[i].getName();
    String sl[] = fn.split( "-" );
    int num = Integer.parseInt( sl[1] );

    if( num >= min && num <= max )
         //do stuff
}
```

Comment: This is susceptible to an injection attack in which a contains a '-'. For example, suppose the file name is "file-name-12345-file.txt".

Comment: I assumed from the question that the a and b part were unknown, and if that was the case having the delimiter as part of the value when parsing something like that just breaks it down anyway. I guess it really depends on what A and B are and how specific you need to be...but it looks like split won't solve the question anyhow.

Comment: My implementation of split solves this. However, both of our implementations are susceptible to injection in the rejex, such as a \\ ("\\\\").