# Notepad++/Regular Expressions search and replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm new to regular expressions so this isn't strictly a Notepad++ question. Here's the text I'm searching through to do a find-and-replace:

```
$AsgTRNonCapCases = $row['AsgTRNonCapCases'];  $AsgRCCapDefs = $row[16];  $AsgRCCapCases = $row[17];  
$AsgRCNonCapDefs = $row[''];  $AsgRCNonCapCases = $row[19];  $DispGPCapDefs = $row[20];  
$DispGPCapCases = $row[''];  $DispGPNonCapDefs = $row[22];  $DispGPNonCapCases = $row[23];  
$DispDDCapDefs = $row[''];  $DispDDCapCases = $row[25];  $DispDDNonCapDefs = $row[26];  
$DispDDNonCapCases = $row[''];  $DispNPCapDefs = $row[28];  $DispNPCapCases = $row[29];  
$DispNPNonCapDefs = $row[''];  $DispNPNonCapCases = $row[31];  $DispODCapDefs = $row[32];  
$DispODCapCases = $row[''];  $DispODNonCapDefs = $row[34];  $DispODNonCapCases = $row[35];  
$DispBTACapDefs = $row[''];  $DispBTACapCases = $row[37];  $DispBTANonCapDefs = $row[38];  
$DispBTANonCapCases = $row[''];  $DispBTCCapDefs = $row[40];  $DispBTCCapCases = $row[41];  
$DispBTCNonCapDefs = $row[''];  $DispBTCNonCapCases = $row[43];  $DispJTACapDefs = $row[44];  
$DispJTACapCases = $row[''];  $DispJTANonCapDefs = $row[46];  $DispJTANonCapCases = $row[47];  $DispJTCCapDefs = $row[''];  $DispJTCCapCases = $row[49];  $DispJTCNonCapDefs = $row[50];  $DispJTCNonCapCases = $row[51];  $DispADDCapDefs = $row[''];  $DispADDCapCases = $row[53];  $DispADDNonCapDefs = $row[54];  $DispADDNonCapCases = $row[''];  $DispSCDCapDefs = $row[56];  $DispSCDCapCases = $row[57];  $DispSCDNonCapDefs = $row[58];  $DispSCDNonCapCases = $row[''];  $DispCTOCapDefs = $row[60]; $DispCTOCapCases = $row[61];  $DispCTONonCapDefs = $row[''];  $DispCTONonCapCases = $row[63];  $OldCapDefs = $row[64];  $OldCapCases = $row[65];  $OldNonCapDefs = $row[''];  $OldNonCapCases = $row[''];
```

All I've been trying to do is replace the $row[##] with $row [''].

I've tried:

```
\[##\]
\[0-100\]
```

and a few others, to no avail. Am I doing something wrong? I have the regular expression checkbox checked.

Comment: Can you please explain better what do you want to do?

Comment: @tim-h I can't understand what you mean by "replace the $row[##] with $row ['']"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use

```
\[[0-9]+\]
```

Which means

- `\[`        a `[` symbol (escaped since `[` has a special meaning in regular expressions).
- `[0-9]`  means any digit
- `+`          means one or more of the previous symbol
- `\]`      a `]` symbol.

Your attempt is slightly wrong:

- `#` has no special meaning in regular expressions.
- `0-100` (if put in brackets, as `[0-100]`) means all characters from `0` to `1` plus `0` and `0`, i.e. it's effectively the same as "zero or one".

---

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349161/how-to-generate-a-regular-expression-at-runtime-to-match-a-numeric-range) for generating a regular expression matching a specific numerical range.

Comment: Thanks!! I will accept your answer once it lets me. The regex patterns I was looking at for this class I'm taking pertain to a certain program, and the # must be specific to that program.

Answer (score 1):

don't have notepad++,but could you try:

```
\[\d{2}\] 
\[[0-9][0-9]\]
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Understanding RegEx with Notepad++](http://blog.creativeitp.com/posts-and-articles/editors/understanding-regex-with-notepad/)