# value less than 99999999.9999

Tags: java, regex

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^\\d{0,8}\\.\\d{0,4}$");
```

is working, but if I enter value e.g 5000, it should work. Basically valid value should be equal or less than "99999999.9999".

If value is "123456789" it is invalid.

Decimal point is not mandatory.

Please help.

Comment: So include the dot and everything after it in a `(...)?` group.

Comment: 99999999.88888888 is lower but has more digits after the decimal point.

Comment: Perhaps related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349161/how-to-generate-a-regular-expression-at-runtime-to-match-a-numeric-range

Comment: You don't need a regex for this.

Comment: Never use regex for working with numbers.. regex is for strings..

Comment: While it is possible to write a regular expression to do this, it's absolutely horrible. Truly awful. **DO NOT DO IT THIS WAY.** There's a lovely static `Double` method for parsing which will be far more satisfactory.

Answer (score 4):

Since every floating-point number has many different representations (think `100`, `100.0`, `1e2`, etc), I'd suggest parsing the number into a `double`, and then using a numeric comparison to establish whether it's within the desired range.

Answer (score 3):

make the decimal part optional

```
^\d{0,8}(\.\d{0,4})?$
```

but i think you mean until only `12345678` but if not

```
^\d{0,9}(\.\d{0,4})?$
```

but i'm proposing to have atleast `1` number after a decimal so if the user tries to enter `123.` it will fail

```
^\d{0,9}(\.\d{1,4})?$
```

Comment: replace that part `(\.\d{0,4})?` with `(\.\d+)?` to match numbers with more digits after the decimal point but are still smaller from the mathematical aspect